# Checking for an instance of a sub class in a list and returning the object

Tags: java, list, if-statement, return, instanceof

I have two objects A and B. Where B is an extension of A.

and I have a list that can contain As and Bs

and I have a method that goes something like:

```
B findB()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ABlist.size(); i++)
    {
        if(ABlist.get(i) instanceof B)
        {
                return ABlist.get(i);
        }
        else{return null;}
    }
    return null;
}
```

which is supposed to look through all the objects in the list and return the object if it is an instance of B. But im getting an incompatible types error because an A cannot be converted to a B.

How would be the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: You need to cast the result of `get(i)`. You shouldn't have that `else`. You should also use an iterator instead of indices.

Comment: Also, don't return `null` in the `else`, just remove the `else` entirely. With @SotiriosDelimanolis' suggestion, this code would only return a non-null instance of `B` if it happens to be first in the list.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that worked, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of doing `instanceof`, you could add a method to class and its subclasses which returns `this` for specific subclass and `null` for other subclasses. Like this:

```
class A {
  public A get() {
    return null;
  }
}
class B extends A {
  @Override
  public A get() {
    return this;
  }
}
...
B findB() {
    for (A a : ABlist) {
        if (a.get() != null) {
            return (B) a;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The idea is to avoid `instanceof` usage when possible. This operator is the part of the language, but wide usage of reflection and `instanceof` can make your application slow and unmaintainable.